# What is "//= require" in a JavaScript file in a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm looking at the source code of a Ruby on Rails app. Several of the JavaScript (*.js and *.es6) files in the source have one or more lines at the top of the file like:

```
//= require path/to/some_other_js_file
```

What are these lines called, and what are they doing?

(Potentially helpful SEO for folks who may be *searching* for a question like this, as I myself did prior to asking: `slash slash equals require`; `double slash equals require`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "Sprockets directives," part of the Rails Asset Pipeline, part of how Rails performs combining and fingerprinting of JavaScript and CSS assets.

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, in particular section [2.4 Manifest Files and Directives](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).